# .htaccess: rewrite all requests to resolve.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to make one page control all incoming requests. *[Is that a good choice?]*

This feature bans bruteforcing of directories and files with, say, DirBuster.
My website's public_html looks like this:

```
data/
    <files and libraries>
    .htaccess
index.php
.htaccess
```

The `data/.htaccess` file only contains `Deny from all`.

What is the query for `/.htaccess` to redirect everything after first slash

> website.com/**query?a=b&c=d**

to

> website.com/index.php?resolve=**query%3Fa%3Db%26c%3Dd**

To use like this:

```
[index.php]

<?php
    if(isset($_GET["resolve"])){
         $URL = $_GET["resolve"];
         require("data/resolve.php");
         exit;
    }
?>
```

```
[data/resolve.php]

<?php
    echo "Resolving " . $URL;
?>
```

---

**UPDATE**

I'm using this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?u=$1 [NC,QSA]
```

And this is the dump of `$_SERVER`:

```
Array
(
    [REDIRECT_UNIQUE_ID] => WPNBPFfUF3-ZHr123R9sKVVAAAAAY
    [REDIRECT_PHP_DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /storage/h1231/8412316/1388846/public_html
    [REDIRECT_DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /storage/h2134/846/138123231846/public_html
    [REDIRECT_SERVER_ADMIN] => webmaster@000webhost.io
    [REDIRECT_STATUS] => 200
    [UNIQUE_ID] => WPNBPFfUF3-ZHrCR123KVVAAAAAY
    [PHP_DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /storage/h14/84123/1238846/public_html
    [DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /storage/h14/846/1312346/public_html
    [SERVER_ADMIN] => webmaster@000webhost.io
    [HTTP_CONNECTION] => Keep-Alive
    [HTTP_PROXY_CONNECTION] => Keep-Alive
    [HTTP_HOST] => fanfiction-app.ml
    [HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO] => http
    [HTTP_X_REAL_IP] => RE.DA.CT.ED
    [HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR] => RE.DA.CT.ED
    [HTTP_X_DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /storage/h123/1236/11236/public_html
    [HTTP_X_OPEN_BASEDIR] => /opt/awex-pages:/storage/h14/846/1388846
    [HTTP_X_UPSTREAM] => php71_7
    [HTTP_X_SERVER_ADMIN] => webmaster@000webhost.io
    [HTTP_X_SERVER_NAME] => website.com
    [HTTP_X_AWEX_UID] => 13236
    [HTTP_X_TEMP_DIR] => /storage/h14/846/1123123/tmp
    [HTTP_WE_ARE_HIRING] => 1492336956.980
    [HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL] => max-age=0
    [HTTP_UPGRADE_INSECURE_REQUESTS] => 1
    [HTTP_USER_AGENT] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36
    [HTTP_ACCEPT] => text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp;q=0.8
    [HTTP_DNT] => 1
    [HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING] => gzip, deflate, sdch
    [HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE] => en-US,en;q=0.8,ru;q=0.6
    [PATH] => /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
    [SERVER_SIGNATURE] => 
    [SERVER_SOFTWARE] => Apache
    [SERVER_NAME] => website.com
    [SERVER_ADDR] => 2202:3380:bad:7::126
    [SERVER_PORT] => 80
    [REMOTE_ADDR] => RE.DA.CT.ED
    [REQUEST_SCHEME] => http
    [CONTEXT_PREFIX] => 
    [CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT] => /storage/h14/836/1312346/public_html
    [SCRIPT_FILENAME] => /storage/h13/846/138123846/public_html/index.php
    [REMOTE_PORT] => 34141
    [REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING] => resolve=query.php&a=b
    [REDIRECT_URL] => /query.php
    [GATEWAY_INTERFACE] => CGI/1.1
    [SERVER_PROTOCOL] => HTTP/1.1
    [REQUEST_METHOD] => GET
    [QUERY_STRING] => resolve=index.php&resolve=query.php&a=b
    [REQUEST_URI] => /query.php?a=b
    [SCRIPT_NAME] => /index.php
    [PHP_SELF] => /index.php
    [REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT] => 1492336956.981
    [REQUEST_TIME] => 1492336956
)
```

When getting `website.com/query?a=b`, however the output of `$_GET["resolve"]` is `query.php`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found a pure Apache .htaccess solution, but I'm going to accept my own answer since I made a PHP hack that seems to be working.

To achieve such functionality, redirect all traffic to one page. In my situation, it's `index.php`.

```
[.htaccess]

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?resolve=$1 [NC,QSA]
```

```
[index.php]

<?php
    if(isset($_GET["resolve"]) && $_GET["resolve"] != "") {
        $URL = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
        $GET = $_GET;
        require "system/resolve.php";
        exit;
    }

    echo "<pre>";
    echo "Requested /";
    echo "</pre>";
?>
```

```
[system/resolve.php]   

<?php

/**
 *  $URL: Full URL query after the slash.
 *  $GET: All get parameters of the query.
 */

    switch($_GET["resolve"]){
        case "ping":
            require "system/ping.php";
            exit;
        case "auth":
            require "system/auth.php";
            exit;
    }
?>
```

In result, when you request http://example.com/ping, you will see a page from `system/ping.php`

Answer (score 0):

Add this to `.htaccess` file as the first lines.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?resolve=$1 [QSA]
```

Where `$1` matches `query?a=b&c=d`

Comment: Using `<...> /index.php?resolve=$1 [L]` generates a 500 Error. Using `<...> index.php?resolve=$1 [L]` partially works: the URL is always "index.php"

Comment: I found out about the [QSA flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa), but GET parameters are not passed: [image](https://i.gyazo.com/bf10608ffce7f2687867b6b8c425df5e.png) when using `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?u=$1 [QSA]`

Comment: Your edited answer is partially correct. The thing is it ignores GET query parameters.